# Alarm manager not triggering alarms at exact time in android

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I scheduled alarm using Calendar class as below

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,1);
cal.getTimeInMillis();  
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,05);
long TriggerMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);      
aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, TriggerMillis,pIntent);
```

where pIntent is an pending intent to proceed further when alarm triggers.

The event triggers with few seconds delay. Is that any problem using Calendar class for this task. Any suggestions?

TIA..

Comment: What is `pIntent`? Is it a `PendingIntent` for a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: Are you targetting API level 19? If so, it's by design. Alarm time won't be exact.

Comment: @CommonsWare pIntent is a pendingIntent to launch a service.

Comment: @Tobor Yes I'm targeting API level 19. Is there any other way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 11):

You have two issues:

1. It is not reliable to use a `_WAKEUP` alarm with a service directly. The only reliable patterns involve `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, my `WakefulIntentService`, or something along those lines, where the `PendingIntent` will be to a `BroadcastReceiver`.
2. If your `android:targetSdkVersion` is 19 or higher, and you are running on an API Level 19+ device, `set()` is inexact. Ideally, you allow it to be inexact, or perhaps use `setWindow()` to control how off it will be, to minimize the power hit of your alarm event. If it absolutely has to occur at a precise moment, you will need to use `setExact()`. Since `setWindow()` and `setExact()` are new to API Level 19, you will need to fall back to `set()` on older devices, by examining `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and branching accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible to schedule repetitive future task at exact time for API 19+ ? I am facing issue when application is not running in background and device is idle. Thank you.

Comment: @Manmohan: Not really. The closest that you can come is to use `setExact()` and "repeat" yourself (by calling `setExact()` again as part of processing the work from the earlier `setExact()`).  However, on Android 6.0+, even with `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`, this is not very exact.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the function

```
setExactAndAllowWhileIdle
```

For example:

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 100, pendingIntent); // +100 is to set nearly to the current time
```

You have to know that **this is not a repeating alarm**, so at the end of your BroadcastReceiver you should set the next alarm.

Regards