# Broadcast receiver fires late than it should be

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, alarm

I am trying to fire a receiver at specific time of day which is 12 Am, but sometimes it fires at 1 or 2 AM.

I added a notifcation to my service to know when exactly the receiver start accourding to the alarm, and I find out, it start at 1, or 2 even 3 Am, not as I adjusted.

```
 calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PrefAlarm.class);

 long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

 alarm = (AlarmManager)  getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);

  pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),  PrefAlarm.REQUEST_CODE2,intent ,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

  alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis( ),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pIntent);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alarm manager not triggering alarms at exact time in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355348/alarm-manager-not-triggering-alarms-at-exact-time-in-android)

Comment: It doesn't help.

Comment: It does. Use  methods without "repeatind"

Comment: But I want to repeat the service every day at 12 AM

Comment: so repeat by set a new alarm

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setInexactRepeating()`, the time that it triggers is **inexact**. This means that Android can adjust the trigger time to save battery (usually by delaying the trigger until the device is awake). Read the documentation about `AlarmManager` and `JobScheduler` and about how to get thedesired behaviour for your application.